# Identify "dark blue wing"

Tags: part-identification

Not sure even if it is a wing or maybe it is a fin or a stabilizer or completely something else:

- I have three of them
- Identical pieces and also top/bottom sides are identical
- No ID nor any text/graphics on them.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's [Flag 5 x 6 Hexagonal (x1435)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x1435#T=C). The lack of any numbers explains why "x1435" was used to catalog the piece, back in time when official part numbers were unavailable. Dark Blue coloured element was available in [6 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x1435&colorID=63&in=A).